# How to display the Time Div and the Message div in a single line?

Tags: css

Could you please let me know how can i display the time and the mesage in a single line ??

I desired output must be

**Time** space **Message** Here  (All in a single line )

This is my code

```
<div class="mdv">
<a href="/tips/"><div class="hed1 nav1" style="color:#333;border-radius:4px 4px 0 0">Latest Share Tips</div></a>
                <a href="/tips/437373-buy-tata-communications-ltd-ta/" class="c1">
                <div class="stoc5 mt1">
                        <div class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">5 hours</div>
                        <div class="c1 fl wi80">(Period - Intraday) - Buy Tata Communications Ltd - Target price 433.00</div>
                        <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                </div>
        </a>
                <a href="/tips/437372-buy-bharti-airtel-ltd-bhartiar/" class="c1">
                <div class="stoc5 mt1">
                        <div class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">6 hours</div>
                        <div class="c1 fl wi80">(Period - Intraday) - Buy Bharti Airtel Ltd - Target price 332.25</div>
                        <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                </div>
        </a>
                <a href="/tips/437371-buy-pipavav-defence-offshore-e/" class="c1">
                <div class="stoc5 mt1">
                        <div class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">6 hours</div>
                        <div class="c1 fl wi80">(Period - Intraday) - Buy Pipavav Defence &amp; Offshore Engineering Company Ltd - Target price 89.60</div>
                        <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                </div>
        </a>
                <a href="/tips/437370-buy-praj-industries-ltd-prajin/" class="c1">
                <div class="stoc5 mt1">
                        <div class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">6 hours</div>
                        <div class="c1 fl wi80">(Period - Long term) - Buy Praj Industries Ltd - Target price 150.00</div>
                        <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                </div>
        </a>
                <a href="/tips/437369-sell-acc-ltd-acc-at-1-354-00-f/" class="c1">
                <div class="stoc5 mt1">
                        <div class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">6 hours</div>
                        <div class="c1 fl wi80">(Period - Intraday) - Sell ACC Ltd - Target price 1,330.00</div>
                        <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                </div>
        </a>
<div class="cl"></div>
</div>
```

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/5/

Answer (score 2):

You need your `div`s inside your `.mt1` container to display `inline` rather than `block`, so something like this would work:

```
.mt1 > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/9/

An alternative would be to put all your content inside a single `div` as it doesn't look like you're doing anything with the 4 other `div`s you have or alternatively a `p` or `span`.

My assumption from using 4 divs like you have is that you expect to perform something specific for each, layout, colouring etc, if you can provide more context the answer could be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
<div class="stoc5 mt1" style="display: inline-flex;">
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<span></span>` tags to have a element next to another element. OR use the `display:inline-block;` CSS to get the same results:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/10/)